# How to upload BACPAC file to Blob in Azure

Tags: sql, azure, blob

So frustrating... , Microsoft do not offer help and you have figure out every small thing at the portal ... 
My question is: I try to import my DB to Azure. I created a BACPAC file from the .Bak and when try to import, there's the "*storage" and then when I click on Configure required settings it's opens the "Storage Accounts" tab but give the message "Not found".

Here's the thing: I created storage and container and blob - it's just not find it. So annoying. And on the azure portal it's doesn't say how to create and how to upload the file.

Also, when I create the storage and the blob, there's no option where to Upload the BACPAC file. How do I do it? What's going on with Microsoft?? So unclear...

To summarize:

1. How do I create a storage/container/blob that when I try to import the DB it will see it?
2. How do I upload the BACPAC to the Azure Blob Storage?. I couldn't find a way to do that on the portal.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% following your example, but if you have a later version of SQL Server Management Studio, you can right click the database you want to deploy, click 'Tasks/Export data tier application'.  In there you can connect to a storage account which if you press Connect, you will have to type the name of the account from the portal and provide a key.  You can then export it to storage and then if you connect to the Azure instance, you can right click the databases level and 'import data tier application'.  If you need to create a storage account in the first place, you do that in the portal, but sounds like you have.

If you want to browse your storage and drop a file in directly, I use Azure Storage Explorer.  There are various tools out there some free some not to do this.  You could of course code your own interface as the API's are published.

Answer (score 1):

View the portal as the administration of your subscription. When you want to use the services (not configure them) - you'll need to look at the toolsets. 
Azure Storage Explorer makes navigating and uploading/downloading files in storage accounts super simple. Visual Studio works well too, for Db workloads Sql Management Studio has Azure integration. If all else fails, powershell gives you the finest level of control.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create an Azure storage account

2 - Create a blob in the new storage account

3 - Access the blob and upload your bacpac file

4 - Access the Sql server, go to import database and use the link "select the backup" to indicate in the blog the bacpac file you want to use to create the database